# Is Bazel good for mobile+desktop project?

Tags: gradle, build, cmake, bazel, build-system

I am looking for a relible build system for my ongoing cross-platform c++ project.
It's meant to be *IOS* (Obj-C (SWift?) + c++), *Android* (Java (Kothlin?) + cpp via NDK/Jni bridge) app, and probably *osx* and *windows* as well.

Although it's highly likely that desktop platforms are meant to be a 'development' platforms only (not production ones).

I considered gradle, but it didn't look like the best solution for ios and/or desktop platforms.

Of course, there is well known and well-proven cmake, but I personlly don't like it. I haven't had any experience with cmake on Android, and want to try something new and modern at the moment.

Bazel (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html) looks promissing for me, but I am wondering how hard it might be to create 4 native project from one codebase/project structure.

In other words, I want to create one common make file for the 4 different platforms. When changes is going to be made, I'd like to make them only once and get all my four build working.

I believe, I understand platform dependant staff. The question is about possibility to have 1 common project for 4 different platforms.

Is it feaseble to acheive this with Bazel?
Or you could reccommend anything else either?

Answer (score 1):

I think Bazel is the perfect solution for you. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Apress/beginning-bazel) repository.

Take a look on [chapter_9](https://github.com/Apress/beginning-bazel/tree/master/chapter_09) (Android app) and [chapter_10](https://github.com/Apress/beginning-bazel/tree/master/chapter_10) (iOS app).